# Please explain AWS services $0.00 per GB IN bandwidth pricing to me

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm thinking of moving one of my small projects off my VPS into amazon cloud for several reasons I wont go into here. I'd like to experiment with their free tier first. I noticed the bandwidth limitation of

> 15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services

However I also noticed on the pricing bandwidth pricing page this

> Data Transfer **IN** To Amazon S3 Pricing
>
> All data transfer in  **$0.000** per GB

I pull in about 300GB a month into my server and push out hardly anything.

Does that mean I won't be charged at all while I'm on the free tier and only downloading data to my instance?

Answer (score 0):

Just answered my own question using their cost calculator, looks like 500GB IN will still keep it all free :-)

Comment: Most of the use case will create mutch more out than in tranfert.  They will need to size there connections to the Internet base on out trafic, so they will have lot of non used in capacity.  If you are lucky, your use case have more in than out.  Trafic will then being payed by pepole watching movies ;)

Comment: You answered your own question almost entirely correctly.  Remember that in TCP, when data flows one way, handshakes and acknowledgments also flow the other way... so even if 100% of your payload is inbound, you'll generate a small amount of outbound overhead traffic.  This is almost always negligible, but worth mentioning in the interest of thoroughness.  Detailed billing and estimated billing alarms are available in the console, so you can avoid surprises.